# How to draw with mouse?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to make a simple mspaint. Firstly, I draw lines in the mouse event.

```
private void pnl_Draw_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(startPaint)
    {
        g = pnl_Draw.CreateGraphics();
        g.DrawLine(p, new Point(initX ?? e.X, initY ?? e.Y), new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        initX = e.X;
        initY = e.Y;
    }
}
```

And then, I realized that all would be resolved if the form was minimized. However, How do I use the onpaint event to do it? Should I store all the points in a list when the user click and move, and then paint and clear them in the onpaint event?

Comment: I assume Winforms? (Tag it please!) _Should I store all the points in a list when the user click and move, and then paint and clear them in the onpaint event?_ Yes! (paint that is, not clear!) At least the first few hundreds. After a while it may be a good idea to use DrawToBitmap to paint/cache  into a Bitmap you can then use as the backgroundimage of your panel and delete the first points.. also make sure to use a double-buffered panel subclass or, better yet, a picturebox! - Also study the difference between DrawLine and DrawLines and also DrawCurves!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep a copy of the last image as a bitmap object. Everything user does should update this object in the memory. You can also handle OnPaint event of your canvas to display this bitmap object as a background image.